# Is there any reliable alternative to IMPORTRANGE()?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importrange, google-sheets-custom-function

After some time the formula breaks, and shows `Error: Loading data...`, and it won't work until I change anything in the parameters, e.g. `Sheet1!a3:Ag` to `Sheet1!a3:AG`, then it works for a few days, and then breaks again with the same error.

I've tried `myImportrange` custom function:

```
// to be used in the spreadsheet like ImportRange, 
// i.e. like this: =myImportRange( "key" ; "sheet!range" ; GoogleClock() )
// the third parameter - GoogleClock() - triggers an automatic update every minute.
// updated 2011-07-17 (ahab): better regex to strip sheetname of *outer* single quotes
function myImportRange(key ,sheetrange) { 
 var shra = sheetrange.split("!") ;
 if (shra.length==1) shra[1]=shra[0], shra[0]="";  

 var sheetstring = shra[0].replace( /^'(.*)'$/g , "$1") // was: replace( /'/g , "") ; updated 2011-07-17 (ahab)
 var rangestring = shra[1] 

 var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById( key )    
 if ( sheetstring.length==0 ) sheet = source.getSheets()[0] ;
 else sheet = source.getSheetByName( sheetstring ) ;

 return  sheet.getRange( rangestring ).getValues(); 
}
```

But eventually received the same error.

Comment: Yes, I am using new Google Sheets. But the formula 
`=myIMPORTRANGE(...;GoogleClock())` worked for few weeks.
Until now, that I get the same `Error: Loading Data ...`

Answer (score 1):

From [Migrate to the New Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/sheets)

> **Custom function arguments must be deterministic**
>
> Built-in spreadsheet functions that return a different result each
>   time they calculate — such as NOW() or RAND() — are not allowed as
>   arguments to a custom function in the new version of Sheets. If a
>   custom function tries to return a value based on a volatile built-in
>   function, it will display Loading... indefinitely.